# how to convert a string object to a lambda function object in python

Tags: python, string, function, lambda

I have a list of strings which contains lambda functions like this:

```
funcs = ["lambda x: x * x", "lambda x: x + x"]
```

And I want to use these functions as we use lambda. If I had this for example:

```
funcs = [lambda x: x * x, lambda x: x + x]
a = funcs[0](3)
print(a)

> 9
```

But first I need to convert this string to a `lambda` to use it as `lambda`. How will I do that?

Comment: Did you try `eval()`?

Comment: `[eval(i) for i in funcs]` ?

Comment: How was the list of strings generated? This is an odd thing to want to do and maybe your issue is upstream

Comment: OK. I didn't know about eval(). It works really fine. Thank you...

Comment: @BurakBaysal Please beware with this new knowledge. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/66516837/13552470

Comment: @AnnZen Thank you for your warning. The input will be always `"lambda x: x*x"` type so there is nothing to worry about in my situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `eval` builtin function, see the [part of the docs about it](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval)

For instance:

```
funcs = ["lambda x: x * x", "lambda x: x + x"]
funcs = [eval(func_str) for func_str in funcs]
```

However, keep in mind that the use of `eval` is a security risk and therefore, in order to prevent code injection, you need to make sure that the strings do not come from user input or that the usage scope of the script is private

Comment: Be aware this will evaulate aribrutary code and can be a security risk, e.g. `eval('__import__("os").listdir()')`

Answer (score 1):

**WARNING: The `eval()` method is really dangerous, so please don't do this. See here: [Why is using 'eval' a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1832940/13552470)**

At your own risk, you can use the `eval()` method to evaluate a string as code:

```
funcs = ["lambda x: x * x", "lambda x: x + x"]
funcs = list(map(eval, funcs))
a = funcs[0](3)
print(a)
```

Output:

```
9
```

The line `list(map(eval, funcs))` uses the built-in [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) method to map the [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) method to each string in the array.

---

There's also this neat article on the topic: [Eval really is dangerous](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)